# 2 Microsoft Accounts - Share DevOps organizations/projects

Tags: azure, microsoft-account

Somehow I have 2 Microsoft Accounts with the same email.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bhA7.png
```

The only difference marked with a red oval.

The problem is when I work with Azure Deployment Center I see only one organization. The organization I've created with account that has Azure subscription (the second account has no subscription)

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fwad.png
```

I need somehow to make trusted relations between 2 accounts or share projects or share organization or even merge 2 accounts into one.

Any suggestions ?